# what's the difference between using RBLs and anti-spam software?

Tags: email, postfix, spam-prevention, spamassassin

My doubt is, is it too different to use RBLs instead of anti-spam programs? (like SpamAssassin)

I've a Postfix + Dovecot server with some RBLs in Postfix, and disabled SpamAssassin because it was giving me struggles. However, then I questioned if it's wise to relay only in RBLs, or if it makes any difference. I suppose that it may also depend on which RBL I use.

I currently have:

- zen.spamhaus.org
- bl.spamcop.net
- cbl.abuseat.org
- combined.rbl.msrbl.net

and used to have dnsbl.sorbs.net, but it blocked some non-spammy mails that I wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what's the difference between using RBLs and anti-spam software?

RBL reference known spammers IP.

Anti-spam software analyse email content looking for well-known pattern to guess if mail is a spam.

That's two totally different mode of behaviour.

> then I questioned if it's wise to relay only in RBLs

To be detected as "spammer" by your Postfix server, an IP must be already known by one of the RBL provider you use.
So, in case of your domain being part of the first wave of spamming for a newly compromised mail server, RBL will be totally useless.

Answer (score 1):

Rejecting SMTP sessions from IP addresses listed in RBL/DNSBL is (relatively) cheap.

Full mail checks are much more resource hungry and should avoid processing "trivial cases".

Do not think about them as alternatives.
Think about them as first and second line of defense/filtetring.
The first line makes it harder to overload the second line.
It is a pretty good **short** explanation IMHO.